# How can I make a newline within a variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm pretty new to Javascript and I ran into a problem. I tried searching it up to find out how to resolve it but I just don't know the specific terms to search so I couldn't find a solution. I was wondering how to add newlines within a variable so that when you render the variable with HTML, it shows it separate by lines, not just "\n" written out.
For example,

```
let foo = "bob<br>is<br>cool"
return (
    <div>
        {foo}
    </div>
)
```

In the browser, this shows as "bob< b r >is < b r >cool", without the spaces. How can I format it so that it shows correctly as bob
is
cool ? Also, how can I write "bob< b r >is < b r >cool" without the spaces but without having the formatting?

Is it possible to concatenate parts to it as well? How would I do

```
foo += "hello<br>"
```

Thanks, sorry if this concept is simple because I somehow didn't stumble upon the solution while searching so I turned to here

Comment: This is not plain Javascript. Are you using React? Please add an appropriate tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's React?

use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: foo }}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for React

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: foo}}> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is REACT,

use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

just like `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: foo }}></div>`

here is example below,

```
function App(){
  const markup={ __html: 'This text is set using </br>dangerouslySetInnerHTML'}
return(
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={markup}>
  
  </div>)
  }
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```